# Build expressions in Data Flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some data in SQL like this:

[image]

Using this query, I am able to get some data:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE TBL_CODE_ALPHA LIKE '%BEG' 
   OR TBL_CODE_ALPHA LIKE '%END'
```

I want to implement the same query in ADF using Data Flows. I tried to build expressions in Data Flows like this:

```
LIKE('FTRANS END', '%END')
```

I getting only true or false values, but I need the actual value.

Comment: You can use filter transformation in dataflow to filter the records which satisfy the conditions. [dataflow screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ztWkadg.png)

Comment: I tried same thing, but here like returns only Boolean values but I need actual value of column

Comment: Can u share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried same thing, but here like returns only Boolean values but I need actual value of column

Use the below expression in the **Filter transformation** to achieve your requirement.

```
like(C4, '%END')
```

**In the expression builder data preview**, it will show `Boolean` values as the output which tells which rows are passed the filter expression and which are not.

[image]

The actual data rows which satisfy the filter condition can be seen in the **Data preview of the Filter transformation** like below.

[image]

You can use this data in later transformations as per your requirement.